# Does a HTML (URL) to PDF converter exist as a widget type service

Tags: .net, html, pdf-conversion

We're trying to shortcut installing a .Net PDF creator on our own server. Is there any app that can be embedded into a site and allows a user to generate a PDF of that url or some other url? Free or paid doesn't matter, to be built for customers so we're trying to find a good quality PDF render too, thanks

PS or can someone build this?

Answer (score 0):

there are websites offering that service for free maybe you can use them: http://www.html-to-pdf.net/free-online-pdf-converter.aspx

Comment: I tried this site earlier today on yahoo and it didn't load a pdf after a minute or so...just tried again and it did so not sure how reliable it is. But I'm really looking for a service/app where I can embed a button in my site that lets a user generate a good quality pdf for that page...the app would download and parse the url then serve up the pdf for download...

Answer (score 0):

yes, there's services like ours: [PDFmyURL](http://pdfmyurl.com), which has a .NET component as well as usage instructions in all other languages.